# Running a command from Ruby displaying output in realtime

Tags: ruby, shell, output

**EDIT: Ok, I got it to work with the below system command. My problem was that I didn't build the command correctly and I got no feedback. What was suggested in comments worked and it gave me feedback to solve the issue.**

I want to run another command (in this case s3cmd which is written in Python, if that matters) from my ruby command and have the output from that command show.

When I run s3cmd from prompt it shows progress and so on.

When I try to run s3cmd from my ruby script with backticks (``) it does not show any of the output from s3cmd. When I try to use popen or something like:

`system("ruby", "s3cmd.rb", out: $stdout, err: :out)`

it either gives me the output when the command is done or it doesn't print at all.

I want the output from the s3cmd to "come through" the ruby script I created.

How do I do that?

Acctual code I'm trying to use is as follows:
`system('s3cmd put "#{item}" s3://[path]',  out: $stdout, err: :out)`

Comment: Try adding `$stdout.sync = true` prior to this line this should flush output immediately as it's running.

Comment: Why not `puts \`command\``?

Comment: @c650 Cause that does not give me realtime output from the command. That gives me no output at all from the command.    engineersmnky Didn't work. I updated the question with the code I try to run.